# How to get back to the tab where the login credential gives error

Tags: jquery, css, laravel

I'm using laravel, I have register and login in one page but different tabs, if someone tried to login with his correct credentials, the site will redirect him to his account so all good here, but if the credentials are  wrong then will back againg to the login page but not to the same tab as he was there, so How can I redirect him to where are the credential gives error either the register or the login tab

```
<div id="whoru">
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="openTabs(event, 'login')"> login </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="openTabs(event, 'schoolregister')"> School Admin </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="schoolregister">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <div>Email address</div>
        <input type="text" id="email">
        <div>Password </div>
        <input type="Password" id="mypassword">
        <div>Confirm password</div>
        <input type="Password" id="password-confirm">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="login">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        <div> Email address </div>
        <input type="email" id="email">
        <div>Password</div>
        <input id="password">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show code where the login is returning an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use **jQuery**

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

Change to a tab:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", destinationTab);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using laravel error bags then get the bags to determine which tab should be opened, you can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#named-error-bags).

You can [manually make validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators) then the code in the controller would look like this :

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('your/previous/route')
               ->withErrors($validator, 'login');
}
```

Then in the view, you can use this to show the tab  :

```
@if ($errors->login) 
    openTabs(event, 'login')
@endif
```

You can make the error bags for register too then add other if logic for register bag